# Creating functions dynamically in Python -- f(2) cannot resolve (f1)

Tags: python, metaprogramming, code-injection, introspection

I am trying to dynamically create 2 functions defined within a string. Code:

```
def  main():

    fns = '''
    def plus_one(x):
    return x + 1


    def plus_two(x):
    return plus_one(x) + 1

    '''
    exec(fns)

    result = eval('plus_two(11)')

    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Saving this code to a file called `dyn_code.py` and running it gives me the following error:

```
python dyn_code.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "dyn_code.py", line 19, in <module>
main()   
File "dyn_code.py", line 14, in main   
result = eval('plus_two(11)')
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>   
File "<string>", line 7, in plus_two 
NameError: name 'plus_one' is not defined
```

Problem here is that `plus_one` cannot be resolved inside `plus_two`.

`plus_one` on its own is fine here and can be called with the correct result.

Can anybody please give me an idea on how to inject code like this into the local namespace? Specifically, I want to create 2 functions, with one referring to the other.

I have intentionally used the most open form of both `exec` and `eval`, I do know how to restrict them, etc. I have also verified that after the call to `exec` both functions are present in the local namespace.

What makes this more frustrating is that the code works fine in an interpreter session! That is, after injecting these 2 functions into the interpreter namespace via `exec`, `plus_two` runs without any issues.

Ideally, I would like to avoid a function-in-function scenario i.e.

```
def plus_two(x):
    def plus_one(x):
        return x + 1

    return plus_one(x) + 1
```

This technique actually works but I want 2 explicitly named and standalone functions.

Comment: The latter approach seems *much* more sensible to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indentations of your function in `fns` matters! and you have to pass `globals()` optional argument for mapping!

```
def  main():
    fns = '''def plus_one(x):
    return x + 1

def plus_two(x):
    return plus_one(x) + 1
    '''
    exec(fns,globals())
    result = eval('plus_two(11)')

    print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
13
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indentation has no effect, I ran the code as is with the globals() and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `globals()` dictionary in your call to `exec()`. You can also omit the eval call for plus_two, like so:

```
def  main():
    exec('def plus_one(x):\n    return x + 1\n\ndef plus_two(x):    return plus_one(x) + 1', globals())
    print(plus_two(11))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I am aware of the eval, I had it for a reason.